# Is there any integrable function in two variables such that it is integrable for any fixed $y$ but the iterated integral does not exist?

Tags: integration, multiple-integral

It can be proven that

> Suppose $f:[a,b]\times[c,d]\to\mathbf R$ is bounded and integrable. For any fixed $y$, suppose
> $$A(y)=\int_a^bf(x,y)\,\mathrm dx$$
> exists. If $\int_c^dA(y)\,\mathrm dy$ exists, then it is equal to the integral of $f$.

The question is why do we need the assumption of the existence of $\int_c^dA(y)\,\mathrm dy$. We (my friends and I) tried finding examples using combinations of the usual "something-if-rational-zero-otherwise" trick but none of them work. Is there such an example?

**EDIT**

Just to clarify, my question is the following. Suppose $f:[a,b]\times[c,d]\to\mathbf R$ is bounded and integrable. Suppose
$A(y)=\int_a^bf(x,y)\,\mathrm dx$
exists for all $y$. Does $\int_c^dA(y)\,\mathrm dy$ necessarily exist?

Comment: You don’t. It’s fubini theorem

Comment: As @Andrew noted, for the Lebesgue integral this is a known theorem.  Perhaps the OP intends the Riemannn integral?  In that case, can we prove this without using the Lebesgue integral?

Comment: Sure, see Theorem 3-10 of Calculus on Manifolds, Spivak.

Comment: @GEdgar: Yes, the question is about the Riemann integral.

Comment: @Andrew: I don't have the book. Can you tell what is the theorem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $f$ is bounded and integrable on $[a,b]\times[c,d]$. I assume  that integrability here pertains to the existence of the multivariate Riemann integral, which I will distinguish from iterated integrals by denoting as

$$\int_{[a,b]\times[c,d]}f(x,y) \,d(x,y)$$

For an example where $A(y) = \int_a^bf(x,y) \, dx$ does not exist as a Riemann integral for every $y \in [c,d]$, take $f: [0,1]\times[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ where

$$f(x,y)= \begin{cases} 0, & x \not\in \mathbb{Q}\\0, & x \in \mathbb{Q}, \,\,y \not\in\mathbb{Q}\\1/q,& x \in \mathbb{Q}, \,\, y=p/q,\,(p,q) =1 \end{cases}$$

Here we have $f(x,y)$ equal to zero if either $x$ or $y$ is irrational, but non-zero and equal to $1/q$ if both $x$ and $y$ are rational with $y = p/q$ in lowest terms.  It can be shown that $f$ has a multivariate Riemann integral by extending the proof for the univariate case [Thomae's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function).  If $y$ is any irrational number in $[0,1]$ then the Riemann integral $A(y)$ obviously exists and takes the value $0$.  However, if $y=p/q$ is a rational number in $[0,1]$, then

$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 1/q, & x\in \mathbb{Q}\\0,& x\notin\mathbb{Q} \end{cases}$$

In this case, $f(\cdot,y)$ is a Dirichlet-type function that is everywhere discontinuous on $[0,1]$ and is not Riemann integrable. Hence, $A(y)$ fails to exist for rational values of $y$.

---

This is actually the worst that can happen, and we have the following:

**Theorem**.  If $f$ is bounded and integrable in the sense of the multivariate Riemann integral on $[a,b]\times[c,d]$,  then the Riemann integral $A(y)= \int_a^b f(x,y) \, dx$ will always exist except possibly on a set of Lebesgue measure $0$.

**Proof:**

Since $f$ is bounded, for any $y \in [c,d]$ there always exist upper and lower Darboux integrals

$$\overline{\int_a^b} f(x,y) \, dx, \quad \underline{\int_a}^bf(x,y) \,dx,$$

and there is a version of Fubini's theorem for Riemann integrals (Munkres, *Analysis on Manifolds*, Theorem 12.2) that states

$$\int_{[a,b]\times[c,d]}f(x,y) \,d(x,y)= \int_c^d\left(\overline{\int_a^b} f(x,y) \, dx\right)\, dy = \int_c^d \left(\underline{\int_a}^bf(x,y) \,dx\right) \, dy$$

Hence,

$$\tag{*}\int_c^d \left(\overline{\int_a^b} f(x,y) \, dx- \underline{\int_a}^bf(x,y) \,dx\right) \, dy = 0$$

Since the integrand in (*) is a nonnegative difference of upper and lower integrals, it must be zero for almost every $y \in [c,d]$ in order that the integral vanish.  In other words, there is a set $S$ of Lebesgue measure zero such that for all $y \in [c,d] - S$, we have

$$\overline{\int_a^b} f(x,y) \, dx= \underline{\int_a}^bf(x,y) \,dx$$

As the upper and lower integrals are equal, it follows that $f(\cdot,y)$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ for all $y \in [c,d]-S$.

Comment: My question was not about whether or not $A(y)$ always exists or not, but rather that, assuming that $A(y)$ exists, can $\int_c^dA(y)\,\mathrm dy$ not exist?

Comment: @ultralegend5385:  Assuming that $f$ is bounded and Riemann integrable (in the multivariate sense over $[a,b]\times[c,d]$ then if $A(y) = \int_a^b f(x,y) \, dx$ exists for each $y$ then $y \mapsto A(y)$ is Riemann integrable -- that is $\int_c^d A(y) \, dy$ exists.  This is a special case of what I showed above in part (2). Even if $A(y)$ does not exist as a Riemann integral the upper and lower integrals $\overline{\int_a^b} f(x,y) \, dx, \quad \underline{\int_a}^bf(x,y) \,dx$ always exist and are themselves integrable over $[c,d]$.

Comment: Hence, if $A(y)$ exists , then $A(y) = \int_a^b f(x,y) \, dx = \overline{\int_a^b} f(x,y) \, dx =   \underline{\int_a}^bf(x,y) \,dx$ and, hence, is integrable.  I also showed that the worst that can happen is $A(y)$ fails to exist for $y$ only on a set of measure zero.